# Iterating through a vector of pointers and printing out values?

Tags: c++

I have something where `firstname_list` is a vector (datatype string) of pointers. So it looks like `vector <string*> firstname_list;`. Inside of this, addresses of strings are stored. If I try to do something like this:

`cout << *(firstname_list[0]);`

It would dereference the address and give me the string I need.

However, I tried to create a loop using an iterator which I read about on this website, and I tried this:

```
vector<string*>::iterator iter;
for (iter = firstname_list.begin(); iter != firstname_list.end(); ++iter)
    cout << *(firstname_array[iter]);
```

However, now it does not print and instead gives an error:

```
error C2679: binary '[' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 

'std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<std::basic_string<cha

r,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> *>>>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

I've looked at other threads similar to this where people ask how to iterate through a loop but I still couldn't figure it out.  Any help as to why I am getting this message is appreciated!

Comment: Just `cout << *iter`.

Comment: `firstname_list`, `firstname_array` what?? Could you please stay consistent.

Comment: cout << *iter; // Use iterator directly.

Comment: I'm curious why you need a `vector<string*>` instead of `vector<string>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, if you're using C++11, then you're lucky.

```
for (const auto& str: firstname_list)
    std::cout << *str << std::endl;
```

Otherwise:

```
vector<string*>::iterator iter;
for (iter = firstname_list.begin(); iter != firstname_list.end(); ++iter)
    std::cout << **iter;
```

*Note:* as mentioned in the comments, you have to dereference the iterator twice. If it was pointing to a `char *`, then a single asterisk would be fine.

Comment: "for (const auto &str: firstname_list)" would've been even better.

Comment: The second one also requires C++11 (`auto`). Also, to print the string (instead of the pointer), you need to dereference twice. `std::cout << **iter;`

Comment: you my friend are a wizard, thank you

Comment: @StacksAndParsing, I can't be a wizard. I'm just... Harry. Just Harry... :)